# How do I create a custom cast interval postgres sql function with Hibernate 6

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin

I have a custom sql dialect that is used to create a timebucket function and a cast interval function that is no longer working after migrating to springboot 3.0.
I was working on migrating this and ran into a roadblock since "SQLFunction" does not exist anymore. Find my old code below:

```
import org.hibernate.QueryException
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.Mapping
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor
import org.hibernate.type.OffsetDateTimeType
import org.hibernate.type.Type

class CustomPostgresqlDialect : PostgreSQL10Dialect() {
  init {
    class CastInterval : SQLFunction {
      override fun hasArguments(): Boolean {
        return true
      }

      override fun hasParenthesesIfNoArguments(): Boolean {
        return true
      }

      @Throws(QueryException::class)
      override fun getReturnType(firstArgumentType: Type?, mapping: Mapping?): Type? {
        return firstArgumentType
      }

      @Throws(QueryException::class)
      override fun render(
        firstArgumentType: Type?,
        args: List<*>,
        factory: SessionFactoryImplementor?
      ): String {
        return "cast(" + args[0] + " as interval)"
      }
    }
    this.registerFunction(
      "time_bucket",
      StandardSQLFunction("time_bucket", OffsetDateTimeType())
    )
    this.registerFunction("castInterval", CastInterval())
  }
}
```

Now I decided to use MetadatabuilderContributor instead of going with a custom dialect again and migrating the time_bucket function was easy enough, but recreating the CastInterval function is proving to be more difficult. I was reading that the SqmFunctionDescriptor is to be used as a replacement for SQLFunction, but im not too familiar with the inner workings of hibernate. The code I have so far is here:

```
class CustomMetadataBuilderContributor : MetadataBuilderContributor {

  override fun contribute(metadataBuilder: MetadataBuilder) {
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
      "time_bucket", StandardSQLFunction("time_bucket", StandardBasicTypes.OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
    )
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("castInterval", CastInterval())
  }
}
```

Any input on how to implement this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should rather use the `FunctionContributor` contract instead.
Implementing this is rather easy, you just register a function pattern:

```
class CustomMetadataBuilderContributor : FunctionContributor {

  override fun contributeFunctions(functionContributions: FunctionContributions) {
    functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().registerNamed(
      "time_bucket", functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeForJavaType(OffsetDateTime::class.java)
    )
    functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().registerPattern(
      "castInterval", "cast(?1 as interval)"
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input. There is one issue here that it complains about the StandardBasicTypes.OFFSET_DATE_TIME: "Required:
(BasicType<Any!>..BasicType<*>?)
Found:
BasicTypeReference<OffsetDateTime!>!"

Comment: Found a workaround: functionContributions.typeConfiguration.getBasicTypeForGenericJavaType(OffsetDateTime::class.java)

Comment: Do I need to register this in the application yaml under hibernate somewhere?

Comment: It uses the service loader mechanism: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html